# What commands can be used with the 'Stack' chatbot?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, chatbot

I only recently found out about the 'Stack' bot that lurks in the chat rooms. The bot doesn't seem to be as well advertised as the other features of Stack Exchange, presumably it's still in development?

All I know about are the two commands *whois* and *summon*. There also doesn't appear to be anything in the FAQ about the bot.

Comment: Those features only work in the moderator chat room, they're not relevant to any other users.

Comment: @Fabian: Ah. That explains why I haven't seen it until now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not really a bot, it's actually just a perversion of a onebox. And it's only active in the moderator chat room. It was the best way to create an unobtrusive method for contacting the moderators of a given site (the mod room is usually pretty crowded, and you just can't know all moderators). The only public instance of such a "reply onebox" is the dice bot in the RPG chatroom.

Comment: While we are on the subject, can we have a "reverse mod lookup" of sorts? Like instead of showing who are the mods for a given site, show which sites a given user has mod privileges?

Comment: I would object to such a feature. It is totally unnecessary, and if interested, who ever wants to know can always refer to [Mark Trapp's list of mods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109889/160166). The other sites a person has mod privileges is displayed in a superscript next to their name.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: What about [that mod's account page](http://stackexchange.com/users/170019/nulluserexception?tab=accounts)? It shows a diamond on each site the person is a moderator.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Sure, but you can look at the [`/about`](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page to find out who are the moderators of a given site. Yet we still have the other feature.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ The other feature actually contacts those mods

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Not the whois.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Yes, but that's obviously something he just threw in because it used the same data as the real feature. You're asking for a whole new feature

Comment: Are you saying it's running on Onebox software?